# Selenium select drop down option of variable passed as a string

Tags: java, drop-down-menu, selenium

Background:

- Card stock - this contains details of the program, location of the stock and country of the stock
- Customer sell card screen - when you sell a new card to a customer, you have to input their address. Once you put in their country, specific fields (state/address line 2/post code) either become mandatory or voluntary.

The problem is the two country databases that are being used are not the same and can differ. "Germany" displayed in the card stock and "Germany, Federal republic of" on the sell card screen

My flow:

1) search the pre-issue card to get the country from the card stock - assign this variable to a string i.e `aString`

2) sell that card

3) in the country drop down box - if `aString` is in that list, select `aString`, if not then create a list of 'else thens' to catch variations

My code keeps telling me that the string is not in the list, `countrydropdown` is printed out as `false` even when I test it with both countries matching

Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
Boolean countrydropdown = "xpath=//select[@id='address.country']/option]".indexOf(aString) > 0;
System.out.println("countrydropdown");
System.out.println(countrydropdown);


<tr>
    <td class="labelFormReq">*</td>
    <td class="labelForm">Country:</td>
    <td>
        <select id="address.country" onchange="validateAndSubmit(this, 'selectCountryEvent');" name="address.country">
            <option value="">Please Select</option>
            <option value="4">Afghanistan</option>
            <option value="248">Alan Islands </option>
            <option value="8">Albania</option>
            <option value="12">Algeria</option>
            <option value="16">American Samoa</option>
            <option value="20">Andorra</option>
            <option value="24">Angola</option>
            <option value="660">Anguilla</option>
            <option value="10">Antarctica</option>
            <option value="28">Antigua and Barbuda</option>
            <option value="32">Argentina</option>
            <option value="51">Armenia</option>
            <option value="533">Aruba</option>
            <option value="36">Australia</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: You know that writing `"xpath=//select[@id='address.country']/option]"` doesn't magically select anything and you need to cover that with a method call, right?

Comment: No I didn't, when I type //select[@id='address.country']/option into xpather, it brings the list of countries up, so I Should be able to index that shouldn't I?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Boolean countrydropdown = "xpath=//select[@id='address.country']/option]".indexOf(aString) > 0;
```

doesn't really search for an element. Actually, it looks for `aString` in the text `"xpath=//select[@id='address.country']/option]"`. In order to make it return anything useful, you have to wrap it with a method call. See this:

```
Boolean countrydropdown = selenium.isElementPresent("xpath=//select[@id='address.country']/option[text()='" + aString + "']");
```

to make a little bit more readable and conventions-aware:

```
boolean countryDropdown = selenium.isElementPresent("xpath=id('address.country')/option[text()='" + aString + "']");
```

It returns `true` if and only if an `<option>` child of the `adress.country` element exists with text equal to your `aString`.

Or, if you want it less oneliney:

```
boolean countryDropdown = false;

String[] countryOptions = selenium.getSelectOptions("id=address.country");
for (String option : countryOptions) {
    if (option.equals(aString)) {
        countryDropdown = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, are you absolutely sure you want to use Selenium RC and not Selenium WebDriver? Selenium RC has been deprecated over a year ago and is not under any development (unlike WebDriver), because it suffered from some serious technical limtations...

Comment: Thanks slanec, I'll try that as soon as I can access the system.

Comment: I tried using web driver but it wouldn't work properly on the system I'm testing. Testing need to be done in ie and web driver kept selecting the next radio tab, in ff it was completely fine. Maybe I'll get my testing completed in rc then switch to web driver. I did loose a couple of days trying to make it work!